# Parse a XML spreadsheet file exported from Microsoft Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to use VBScript to parse a XML spreadsheet file exported from Microsoft Excel. I started by trying to count number of the `<Row>` elements. However the script always return 0. What did I do wrong?

Here is my VBScript file:

```vb
Set oXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

oXML.aSync = false
oXML.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
oXML.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
oXML.validateOnParse = False
oXML.resolveExternals = False

oXML.Load "_test_.xml"

MsgBox oXML.SelectNodes("//Row").length ' Return 0

WScript.Quit

' Looping through all nodes works fine
Set nodes = oXML.selectNodes("//*")    
For i = 0 to nodes.length -1 
    Msgbox nodes(i).nodeName
Next
```

And here is the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <Version>14.00</Version>
    </DocumentProperties>
    <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <AllowPNG/>
    </OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2" x:FullColumns="1"
        x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">First Row</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Second Row</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there are multiple namespaces, you must define those namespaces for the XPATH. This must be done even for the default namespace. If not, you cannot get concrete elements from namespaces using XPATH. Thats why `//*` will work but `//Row` will not work because XPATH does not know which namespace `Row` belongs to.

Setting the namespaces will be done using [setProperty Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See also [Second-Level DOM Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SelectionNamespaces Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Your example:

```vb
Set oXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

oXML.aSync = false
oXML.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
oXML.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
oXML.validateOnParse = False
oXML.resolveExternals = False

oXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:d=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""" & _
  " xmlns:o=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office""" & _
  " xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel""" & _
  " xmlns:ss=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet""" & _
  " xmlns:html=""http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"""

oXML.Load "_test_.xml"

MsgBox oXML.SelectNodes("//d:Row").length ' Return 2

' Looping through all rows in Table
Set nodes = oXML.selectNodes("//d:Table//*")    
For i = 0 to nodes.length -1 
    Msgbox nodes(i).nodeName
Next
```

In that example I have prefixed the default namespace with `d`.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers: I've never understood what some people have against transparency of link URIs in IT technical texts. But so be it. ;-)

Comment: IMO literal URLs in a text impede reading fluency, so I prefer to make them into "regular" links. I don't think this really hurts link transparency, because unlike with URL shorteners you can still see the full URL when hovering the mouse cursor over the link.

Comment: Everything is good now. I have learned a thing or two. Thank you very much for your lesson :)